# Axios Post Form with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, post, axios

So I have this post method with Axios and if I submit this, it said

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
>       at createError (createError.js:16)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)

If I use this method:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/users', ({userid: this.state.userid})
```

it works. But if I add 2 or more arg to the axios post it gets error again:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/users', ({userid: this.state.userid}, {fullname: this.state.fullname} ))
```

Here is my full code. As you can see I try different combinations of code, and it only works if I only pass 1 arg.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
// import { Form } from 'antd';
// import { List, Card, Form } from 'antd';

export default class FormUser extends React.Component {
    // constructor(props) {
    //   super(props)
    //   this.state = {
      state = {
        userid: '',
        fullname: '',
        usergroup:'',
        emailid: '',
        mobile: '',
        title: '',

  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ userid: event.target.value });
    this.setState({ fullname: event.target.value });
    this.setState({ usergroup: event.target.value });
    this.setState({ emailid: event.target.value });
    this.setState({ mobile: event.target.value });
    this.setState({ title: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // const userform = {userid: this.state.userid};
    // const fullnameForm = {fullname: this.state.fullname};
    // const usergroupForm = {usergroup: this.state.usergroup};
    // const emailidForm = {emailid: this.state.emailid};
    // const mobileForm = {mobile: this.state.mobile};
    // const titleForm = {title: this.state.title};

    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/users', ({userid: this.state.userid}, {fullname: this.state.fullname} )) 
    // { {userid: this.state.userid}, {fullname: this.state.fullname} , usergroup: this.state.usergroup, emailid: this.state.emailid, mobile: this.state.mobile, title: this.state.title }) 
    // { userform, fullnameForm, usergroupForm, emailidForm, mobileForm, titleForm }) 
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>User Project ID:  <input type="text" name="userid" onChange={this.handleChange}/></label><br/>
        <label>Full Name:  <input type="text" name="fullname" onChange={this.handleChange}/></label><br/>
        <label>User Group:  <input type="text" name="usergroup" onChange={this.handleChange}/></label><br/>
        <label>Email:  <input type="text" name="emailid" onChange={this.handleChange}/></label><br/>
        <label>Mobile:  <input type="text" name="mobile" onChange={this.handleChange}/></label><br/>
        <label>Title:  <input type="text" name="title" onChange={this.handleChange}/></label>
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

AXIOS POST on Express

```
app.post('/users', function (req, res) {
  var postData = req.body;
  // postData.created_at = new Date();
  connection.query("INSERT INTO users SET ?", postData, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(results.insertId);
    res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
  });
});
```

Comment: Unrelated to the actual question, but with a `handleChange` handler like that, all of your state fields will end up having the same value. Also, since the <input>s don't have a `value` prop, they're uncontrolled, which is likely not what you want.

Comment: Should I change to this? <input type="text" name="this.state.userid" onChange={this.handleChange}/>

Comment: I suggest (re-)reading the React docs on forms. https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

eventHandler for each state. Is there any way I can do this better?
yes it would work something like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class UserForm extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      fname: '',
      lname: '',
      email: '',
    };
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    /*
      Because we named the inputs to match their
      corresponding values in state, it's
      super easy to update the state
    */
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    const { fname, lname, email } = this.state;
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="fname"
          value={fname}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="lname"
          value={lname}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

and about submission of the form your axios post would work something like this

```
onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // get our form data out of state
    const { fname, lname, email } = this.state;

    axios.post('/', { fname, lname, email })
      .then((result) => {
        //access the results here....
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

`axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`'s 3rd argument is the Axios configuration object, which you're inadvertently passing in in

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/users', ({userid: this.state.userid}, {fullname: this.state.fullname} ))
```

so the request gets misconfigured and doesn't work.

Instead, all of the data to POST should be in the single `data` object.

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/users', {
  userid: this.state.userid,
  fullname: this.state.fullname,
})
```

Comment: So is there something listening for the POST at http://localhost:5000/ ? Is your React application also on http://localhost:5000/ ? If they're on different origins, you'll need to set up CORS so the React app can talk to the backend.

Comment: Yes, I have cors setup and running. Express is at 8000. As I said earlier, a single post data works, but not if there are 2 or more data. How can I change the state to array of object? Is that possible?

Comment: Look at the Network tab in your browser's console to see what the actual payload being sent is and what the actual network error is. It could be a 400 or 500 from your app.

Comment: If I post 2 data, it said Access-Control-Request-Headers: content type and below it Access-Control-Method: POST. If post a single data, there’s console log with the data.

Comment: So I just noticed that the single data actually got recorded to the database, the other fields are empty.

Comment: Is your Express server configured to accept JSON data?

Comment: Here's a quick Codesandbox example using a remote CORS-enabled server, and it does work, though as you can see in the inspector, the payload is sent as a single JSON object, as is the default for Axios. https://codesandbox.io/s/94xq657qyo

Comment: I already added the post section that receive json data. And I use Postman and it works and the data from Postman added to the database successfully.

Comment: So then there's something off with the data. Please use the network tab to inspect the request that's being sent... https://i.imgur.com/PB2RoqO.png

Comment: So I use this code: axios.post('http://localhost:5000/users',
      { userid: this.state.userid, fullname: this.state.fullname, usergroup: this.state.usergroup, emailid: this.state.emailid, mobile: this.state.mobile, title: this.state.title }, )                                           
and change the name="userid" to this code: <input type="text" name="this.state.userid" onChange={this.handleChange}, and all the relevant data, and it works, no error, but all data in the database has the same value, which is "title".

Answer (score 1):

So apparently I have to add eventhandler for each state. Is there any way I can do this better?

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Form } from 'antd';
// import { List, Card, Form } from 'antd';

const FormItem = Form.Item;

export default class FormUser extends React.Component {
  // constructor(props) {
  //   super(props)
  //   this.state = {
  state = {
    userid: '',
    fullname: '',
    usergroup: '',
    emailid: '',
    mobile: '',
    title: '',

  };

  handleUserIDChange = event => {this.setState({ userid: event.target.value })}
  handleFullNameChange = event => {this.setState({ fullname: event.target.value })}
  handleUserGroupChange = event => {this.setState({ usergroup: event.target.value })}
  handleEmailIDChange = event => {this.setState({ emailid: event.target.value })}
  handleMobileChange = event => {this.setState({ mobile: event.target.value })}
  handleTitleChange = event => {this.setState({ title: event.target.value })}

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // const userform = {userid: this.state.userid};
    // const fullnameForm = {fullname: this.state.fullname};
    // const usergroupForm = {usergroup: this.state.usergroup};
    // const emailidForm = {emailid: this.state.emailid};
    // const mobileForm = {mobile: this.state.mobile};
    // const titleForm = {title: this.state.title};

    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/users',
      { userid: this.state.userid, fullname: this.state.fullname, usergroup: this.state.usergroup, emailid: this.state.emailid, mobile: this.state.mobile, title: this.state.title },)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (

      // const formItemLayout = {
      //   labelCol: {
      //     xs: { span: 24 },
      //     sm: { span: 8 },
      //   },
      //   wrapperCol: {
      //     xs: { span: 24 },
      //     sm: { span: 16},
      //   },
      // };

      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <FormItem>
          <label>User Project ID:  <input type="text" name="this.state.userid" onChange={this.handleUserIDChange} /></label>
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          <label>Full Name:  <input type="text" name="this.state.fullname" onChange={this.handleFullNameChange} /></label><br />
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          <label>User Group:  <input type="text" name="this.state.usergroup" onChange={this.handleUserGroupChange} /></label><br />
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          <label>Email:  <input type="text" name="this.state.emailid" onChange={this.handleEmailIDChange} /></label>
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          <label>Mobile:  <input type="text" name="this.state.mobile" onChange={this.handleMobileChange} /></label>
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          <label>Title:  <input type="text" name="this.state.title" onChange={this.handleTitleChange} /></label>
        </FormItem>
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </Form>
    )
  }
}
```